# Symfony plugins not installing?

Tags: php, symfony1

I am having some issues trying to install plugins from symfony into my project:

OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard

MAMP 1.8.2 (PHP 5.2.10)

Symfony 1.2 (standalone symfony framework + project as recommended by the [Symfony Getting Started](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_2/en/01-Introduction) tutorial. e.g. I save the symfony framework in a lib/vendor folder inside my project).

I run the following command to install the sfGuard plugin from inside my symfony project

```
$ ./symfony plugin:install sfGuardPlugin
>> plugin    installing plugin "sfGuardPlugin"
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin Attempting to discover channel "pear.symfony-project.com"...
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin downloading channel.xml ...
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin Starting to download channel.xml (663 bytes)
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin .
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin ...done: 663 bytes
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin Auto-discovered channel "pear.symfony-project.com", alias
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin "symfony", adding to registry
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin Attempting to discover channel
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin "plugins.symfony-project.org"...
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin downloading channel.xml ...
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin Starting to download channel.xml (639 bytes)
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin ...done: 639 bytes
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin Auto-discovered channel "plugins.symfony-project.org", alias
>> sfPearFrontendPlugin "symfony-plugins", adding to registry
```

But when I check the plugins folder there is nothing in it. I run the command again

```
$ ./symfony plugin:install sfGuardPlugin
>> plugin    installing plugin "sfGuardPlugin"
```

When I run the plugin:list command it doesn't indicate that the plugins was installed. This is all I get

```
$ ./symfony plugin:list
Installed plugins:
```

And still nothing. Am I missing something here? Is my pear install not configured properly? Is this a known issue? Does symfony place the plugin code somewhere else? I am used to the symfony 1.0 way of doing things.

Any troubleshooting tips welcome.

Comment: Try to search sfGuardPlugin folder all over the drive. Is it somewhere there? Also, when you do ./symfony plugin:install you need to set your current directory to the project folder. E.g. you need to execute the command from within project folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely end up with multiple versions of Symfony installed if you aren't careful. Try checking your php include path and your pear setup paths.

Comment: Short of reinstalling the whole OS, what is the easiest way to make sure I have symfony and pear uninstalled. So I can start with a clean slate?

Comment: Pear installs Symfony in a separate libs kind of folder and I imagine that is where your plugin is being installed. You might not even have a pear version of symfony installed. You said you are using a sandbox version which is like a standalone setup. I'd delete that version and try getting your php include directories setup to use the pear version wherever that was placed. To uninstall the pear version just use pear uninstall to remove the sandbox version just delete the files from your web folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the author still needs this answer, but maybe someone else found this answer useful.

It seems that the php-pear module isn't installed in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the sfGuard plugin doesn't work with symfony 1.2. Check the plugin's page [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin). It says it only supports symfony 1.3 and 1.4.